# VueJS add class if has filter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

Is there a way to do this filter rule in VueJS?

> If some element has the filter `discount`, the parent will receive the class `color-green` (in this case the tag span)

[I made a JSFIDDLE :)](https://jsfiddle.net/cc28z5d3/86/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>50% Discount =)</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="product in products">
      {{ product.name }} - <span> {{ product.price | discount }} </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.filter('discount', function (value) {
  return  value * 0.5;
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    products: [
      {name: 'Angular', price: 75},
      {name: 'VueJS', price: 60},
      {name: 'React', price: 40}
    ]
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.color-green{
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to you use filters? The best way is definitely to go with components

Comment: I think i was not clear, i edited my question! =)

Comment: filters are only meant to do simple text transformation

Comment: Hmmm is there no way to get the parent tag of filtered element?

Comment: Read the doc if you want, it's pretty short. https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html It's pretty much meant to translate simple strings. Use components or directive for more power

Answer (score 1):

But in your case every element has a discount isn't it?

Filter is not something you want to check. Filter is just a way to transform some input to some output.

Discount info should be defined inside your products data. And then you can make something like this:

```js
Vue.filter('discount', function (value) {
  return  value * 0.5;
})

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: {
   products: [
      {name: 'Angular', price: 75, discount: 0.3},
      {name: 'VueJS', price: 60},
      {name: 'React', price: 40, discount: 0.7}
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.color-green{
  color: green;
}

.product-price--discounted {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Products</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="product in products">
      {{ product.name }} - 
      <span :class="product.discount && 'product-price--discounted'">{{ product.price }}</span>
      <span v-if="product.discount" class="color-green">
        {{ product.price - product.price * product.discount}}
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <h3>All elements has discount:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="product in products">
      {{ product.name }} - <span class='color-green'>{{ product.price | discount }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is not what i want... You put inline the class `color-green`. I want the span `product.price` goes green just because it has `discount` filter. Do you understand? Thanks!

Comment: How do you think you can separate those spans? They all have this filter `<span> {{ product.price | discount }} </span>` discount filter is not something conditional here. It's just transform value from product.price before render.

Comment: Hmmm is there no way to get the parent tag of filtered element?